# Pathfinding algorithm to maximize profit

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, path-finding

Say we have a directed graph where each edge contains a tuple **(d,p)** where **d** is the distance that must be traveled and **p** is the profit you'll get by traversing that edge, and after traversing an edge, it's profit is set to **0**.  My question is, given a starting node and maximum distance **D** (such that **Σd < D** across all edges traversed), solve for the maximum profit, where profit is defined as **Σp** across all edges traversed.

You can revisit nodes and re-traverse edges.

I've attempted to modify dijkstra to no success, since dijkstra doesn't know when to stop it's flood fill, and as far as I can tell there's no way to guarantee the best solution with dijkstra before checking all possibilities. I've also looked into variations of TSP, and this problem seems much more path-finding related.  Any references, pseudocode, or already understood algorithms would be appreciated.  I am, of course, not looking for brute-force algorithms.

Comment: NP-hard by reduction from Hamilton path. Related to the Asymmetric Prize-Collecting Traveling Salesman problem.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes thanks for mentioning it's NP hard, and from what literature I can find on the Asymmetric Prize Collecting TSP it does appear to be quite similar, apart from nodes being visited only once.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat upon further reading, the Prize-Collecting TSP's optimization goal seems quite distant from mine, the Prize-Collecting TSP's goal is to visit a subset of the nodes such that the length of the tour plus the sum of penalties of all nodes not in the tour is as small as possible.  There is no distinct limit on maximum distance traversed, just an attempt to keep it low.

Comment: It's not an exact correspondence, but (after splitting each edge to allow for a prize in the middle) you can approximate APCTSP well with an algorithm for this by trying several different values of D, and this with APCTSP by introducing a Lagrange multiplier. The idea in noting the relation is less to apply an off-the-shelf algorithm for APCTSP and more that ideas used to attack APCTSP may prove useful for this problem.

Comment: How big are the directed graphs that you care about?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat around 100 nodes with 10,000 edges

Comment: @DavidEisenstat And yeah, I'll apparently need to do more research on the algorithms used because I haven't gotten any inspiration from what I've read so far on APCTSP.  But if you say it's there then I'll go off of that.

Comment: I'm writing up an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the scale of the problem, we might have success attacking it with an integer program. For each directed edge `e`, let `x(e)` be a nonnegative integer variable representing the number of times we use the edge, and `y(e)` be a 0-1 variable representing the number of times we profit from the edge. For each vertex `v`, let `w(v)` be a 0-1 variable indicating whether `v` is visited, and `z(v)` be a 0-1 variable indicating whether `v` is the ending vertex. The easy part of the integer program is

```
maximize sum_e p(e) y(e)
subject to
y(e) <= x(e)            # can't profit from an edge if we don't use it
for all e, y(e) <= w(head(e))    # can't profit unless we visit
for all e, y(e) <= w(tail(e))    # can't profit unless we visit
sum_e d(e) x(e) <= D    # bounded distance
sum_v z(v) = 1          # exactly one ending vertex
# path constraints
for all vertices v, sum_{e with head v} x(e) - sum_{e with tail v} x(e) =
    z(v) - 1 if v is the starting vertex,
    z(v)     otherwise.
```

The hard part is preventing cycles to nowhere (analog of the subtour elimination constraint for TSP). If we manage this, then we can find an Euler trail in the subgraph whose edges have multiplicity indicated by the `y(e)`.

We take the same strategy as TSP -- write an exponential number of constraints, enforce them post hoc.

```
for all sets of vertices S containing the starting vertex,
    for all vertices v not in S,
        sum_{directed edges e entering S} y(e) >= w(v)
```

Comment: Starting with the restraints, isn't what we're attempting to maximize `sum_e p(e) y(e)`? since re-traversing an edge doesn't gain you more profit, and `x(e)` can be greater than one.  For the restrictions I don't see why it's necessary to have `x(e) <= y(e)`.  Since you're able to re-traverse edges, doesn't this restraint restrict traversing over an edge to a maximum of once?  wouldn't the correct restriction be `x(e) >= y(e)`?  While I agree with these constraints otherwise, we unfortunately cannot base an algorithm off of restrictions alone.

Comment: I also don't see how an Euler trail would be of any use here, isn't it required that we know the subgraph in advance to determine the Euler trail?

Comment: @Bryce219 got `x` and `y` confused, fixed.

Comment: @Bryce219 the Euler trail turns the use counts into an actual walk.

Comment: Apologies, but I don't understand the link between the constraints and finding the optimal Euler trail.  I agree that the Euler trail which maximizes `sum_e p(e) y(e)` is the solution, but how do the constraints play into discovering that?  Also regarding your second block, is that not just another constraint?  I see no apparent connection to solving for the Euler trail

Comment: @Bryce219 The constraints enforce the existence conditions for an Euler trail in the multiset of edges chosen: in-degree equals out-degree except for the source and sink, plus strong connectivity (the "hard" constraint). The last constraint is different because it expands out to an exponential number of constraints.

Comment: I see.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand these are useful restrictions which preserve the answer and lower the number of possibilities needed to check, but apart from assuming we can just `maximize sum_e p(e) y(e)`, the return type of this algorithm is a relatively large set of graphs which still needed to be checked by brute force.